# Using Like Condition in Join not giving desired output

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables products, items and trying to join using product from products table and item from items table

Products:

| Product | date | Dose |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Acetaminophen | 12/10/2020 | 0.5ml |
| Tylenol | 06/10/2008 | 10ml |
| Amoxycillin 5ml | 01/10/2022 | 0.75ml |
| Penicillin | 8/10/2021 | 1ml |
| Sterile Water | 5/05/2020 | 10ml |
| Sterile Diluent | 5/05/2006 | 15ml |

Items:

| item | date | Dose |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Acetam | 12/10/2020 | 0.5ml |
| Tylenol | 06/10/2008 | 10ml |
| Amoxycillin 5ml | 01/10/2022 | 0.75ml |
| Penicillin | 8/10/2021. | 1ml |
| Steril water | 5/05/2006 | 15ml |

```
Select a.product,a.date,a.dose
 from products a
inner join
items b
on a.product like concat('%',b.item,'%')
```

but I am only getting this output:

| Product | date | Dose |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tylenol | 06/10/2008 | 10ml |
| Amoxycillin 5ml | 01/10/2022 | 0.75ml |
| Penicillin | 8/10/2021 | 1ml |

the desired output should be something like this, I am okay to have 1:many join.

| Product | date | Dose |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Acetaminophen | 12/10/2020 | 0.5ml |
| Tylenol | 06/10/2008 | 10ml |
| Amoxycillin 5ml | 01/10/2022 | 0.75ml |
| Penicillin | 8/10/2021 | 1ml |
| Sterile Water | 5/05/2020 | 10ml |
| Sterile Diluent | 5/05/2006 | 15ml |

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You use an inner join - so why do you expect Acetaminophen to be included in your resultset? You don't include columns from Items in your column list, which makes me suspicious that this is a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Change inner join to left join? Or just don't join at all?

Comment: Your query works as you wish it to. Your issue is you have spelt "Sterile" differently without and "e" e.g. "Steril" so of course it won't match.

Comment: @DaleK- That's how the data looks, I am not mocking any data here. I was looking for if there is a way to join when the data is "Steril" in one table and "Sterile" in another one?

Comment: @SMor It has to be an Inner join, Its my bad that I didn't include the entire query as its very huge. I only copied the glimpse of my query where I am struggling (Joining "Steril" vs "Sterile" as an example)

Comment: "I was looking for if there is a way to join when the data is "Steril" in one table and "Sterile" in another one?" - well you didn't ask that - if you already know that that is your issue please say so. Yes there will be a way to join, but what are the rules for such logic? Only you can define what the rules are for a fuzzy join like that, and I suspect it will be very hard to do so.

Comment: I would be very tempted to have a table of differently spelled words in order to correct his issue, trying to solve it with wildcards is likely to end up with undesired results. Or even, add the product twice to the master table, with the different spellings.

Comment: @DaleK Thanks for your inputs, That makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
;WITH   NewItem AS
    (
        SELECT
                Item
            ,   SearchString =  CASE CHARINDEX(' ', Item) 
                                    WHEN 0  THEN Item 
                                            ELSE LEFT(Item, CHARINDEX(' ', Item)-1) 
                                END
        FROM @Item
    )
SELECT
        Product =   P.product
    ,   Date    =   P.date
    ,   Dose    =   P.dose
FROM    Product P
JOIN    NewItem I   ON  CHARINDEX(SearchString, P.Product) > 0
;
```